# Travelling from Singapore to Canada

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, canada

this is my first time travelling to Canada, Vancouver from Singapore and I am already having some issues/confusions.

As I will be going there for work purposes, I will be bringing along my electronic devices - laptop, phones, psp etc. However I read that there is the possibly of a secondary inspection. Should that happens to me, will I be asked to switch on my devices for them to check? Just the thought of it seems scary for me

Not sure if I can ask this, as far as I know, there is the need to get my work permit (?) at the immigration once I landed, and I may be asked a couple of questions - are they tough to answer?

Then as my sister may be travelling with me, it seems that she will needs the ETA since we are flying there via air (Visa is not required)... However, as I was checking through the Canada site for more info, there just seems to be so many links and I am really confused if any other documents are really needed. As such, just wondering if anyone else would know what other documents may be needed?

Lastly, anyone care to share any tips / info to someone new like me, housing etc?

Comment: @dissidia, you are asking many different questions here. It is best to split them up into separate questions.

Comment: @EugeneO Sorry about that, thought it will be easier to consolidate as a whole rather than seperate threads

Comment: What's scary about switching on your electronic devices? It's just a basic check that the thing you're claiming is a laptop really is a laptop, not the shell of a laptop that's been packed with explosives.